# Using dba_CopyLogins as part of a Database Migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-migration

I'm considering using dba_CopyLogins (found On SQLsoldier [Here](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror), and refrenced in many migration related threads in dba.stackexchange ) to get the logins moved over as part of a migration from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2012.

**Edit: Why not just use Sp_help_revlogin?**
As I understand it (please correct if i'm wrong) sp_help_revlogin comes with a lot of caveats. It does not map the users to the databases, it does not copy over the passwords, it does not handle explicit permissions.. I'm hopeing to avoid using a script to transfer logins that results in me still having to touch 50+ individual logins one at a time.
Most of our user logins (possibly all, but i've not checked each one) are windows logins so maybe I'm making mountains out of mole hills.

I have some questions concerning how to use [dba_CopyLogins] properly, since comments on other user's questions have been unclear/ contradictory or did not address my question, and to call me an "Accidental DBA" would be being kind.

First: I'm migrating from sql 2008 R2 (box A) to Sql 2012 (box B). Is dba_CopyLogins meant to created/run on box A, or on Box B?

Second:  @PartnerServer..is that meant to be the server where the logins exist?
Is this where I put the name of the linked server object?

Third: Box A and B are on different domains, does that matter?

Forth: Just looking for confirmation that this script will fail if a login already exisits with the same name. Will it faily only that login, or will the whole script abort?

Comment: Without looking at that blog, is there a particular reason you are electing not to use the sp_help_revlogin method of migrating logins?

Comment: @RazzleDazzle - edited question to include why not sp_help_revlogin

Answer (score 0):

I used, as in the comments sp_help_revlogin method.

You can read more about it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246133

The script must run on box A and then stored procedure called.

The stored procedure will output script for recreating logins. When you run it on BOX b it will fail just on exsisting logins.

Different domains. Yes. It is a problem. It is a problem if you use integrated security and there is no trust between domains.

But, if you use integrated security and you have the same users in destination domain, with sp_help_revlogin you can adapt the script to map logins to destination domain. I used this method to align stuff.

Another issue is the default db. It will be lost and somtimes this is a problem for some applications (with bad configuration).

I used to run this script on source server and the results on destination server:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_defaultdb ''' + name + ''', ''' + dbname + ''''
FROM master.dbo.syslogins
WHERE [name] IS NOT NULL
AND dbname IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @user-0 The "applies to" in that kb article stops with Sql 2005. Im transfering logins from SQL 2008 R2 over to SQL 2012.
I found this which iseems to be updated. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992